# Tips for designing a minimalist data store suitable for an embedded device

Tags: c, database-design, rest, embedded

I am trying to design a data store implementation like SQLite, BerkeleyDB or CouchDB suitable for a small embedded computer platform. The main criteria is minimal bloat and simple API.

I could not find any products that fit my needs. SQLite is a tad too large and mimics relational databases. CouchDB has a good RESTful API but is bloated.

Basically my goals are:

- Written in C.
- Key-value model preferred over relational model.
- RESTful web server and API.

I am struggling with designing the database backend. What's the best way to store the data? How do I organize it with minimal performance loss? How do other implementations tackle this (SQLite for example)? Is there any literature on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was unsuitable about BerkleyDB (and GDBM, Tokyo Cabinet, etc...)? If it's just REST that they're missing then that's far easier to bolt on than designing a new storage format from scratch.

Comment: @SimonJ I have about 5 megabytes in storage that I can dedicate for Linux kernel and binaries. Also the CPU is about 50 bogomips in speed...

Comment: When BerkleyDB was first popularised, typical desktop PCs were about 50 bogomips.

Comment: SQLite *is* a relational database. Just saying.

Answer (score 2):

try the Qdbm suite (qdbm.sourceforge.net). It' the fastest and more flexible key/value store I've used. You can find a comparaison with other similar packages here:

http://qdbm.sourceforge.net/benchmark.pdf

If the store is read intensive, you can try also the CDB package from DJB.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/) is what you need?